# Как исправить ошибку в Visual studio code при использований npm/

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

[image: Ошибка ниже]

Я пробовал переустанавливать node, и запускать vs code от имени администратора

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Запускайте приложения через обычный Command Prompt или просто через CTRL+F5